# Detecting image translation with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to do a simple task: **having a reference image, compute the translation in pixels of another images** taking into account that there is **no zoom** and **no rotation**, just translation: (x, y). Having this, which is the easies method? autocorrelation? feature extraction? I guess feature extraction is not needed at all since it is a simple task.

Any help would be appreciated,
Cheers,

Comment: I have used SURF for stereoscopic vision algorithms but, in this case, I could not use SURF since it comsumes too much CPU. Thus, I need a simple approach given this simple problem. Your comment is not constructive at all, I just try to ask here since I guess lots of people know a good right simple answer for my question.

Comment: Take a look at [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#matchtemplate).

Comment: Thanks bsdnoobz, I think that's what I was looking for. I'll try and tell you.

Comment: @DídacPérez we can't take your word for the task being simple or not, unfortunately. You might think the problem is simple, but it might be not. If you can include representative images of what you are working with, then it might be possible to tell whether the problem is really simple or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution that achieves my goal:

```
// Prepare required variables
cv::Point point;
cv::Mat correlation;
double max_val;

// Compute the template matching
cv::matchTemplate(image_crop, ref_crop, correlation, cv::TM_CCORR_NORMED);

// Find the position of the max point
cv::minMaxLoc(correlation, NULL, &max_val, NULL, &point);
```

where the point variable contains the translation coordinates x and y.